# If the value is NULL then send something else

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, isnull

Column MaxPlaces sometimes has a value and sometimes is just NULL.
I have to send this procedure to the C# but when NULL is processed within the code the code breaks.

ISNULL is not working the following error appears:

> Additional information: Column 'MaxPlaces' does not belong to table
>   getLvLValue.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLvLValue] @LevID NVARCHAR(100)
 AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT a.BCID
         ,a.CharacteristicID
         ,b.CharacteristicName
         ,a.LevID
         ,ISNULL(b.MaxPlaces, '20')
    FROM BCCharacteristics AS a
    INNER JOIN Characteristic AS b ON a.CharaID = b.CharaID
    WHERE LevID = 1
    AND a.BCID = @LevelID
    AND a.CharaID = b.CharaID;
 END
```

Can someone help me with this problem. Only one parameter needs to be sent and if MaxPlaces is NULL then send the value 20 to the C#.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should provide the column name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLvLValue] 
   @LevID  nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT a.BCID, a.CharacteristicID, b.CharacteristicName, a.LevID, ISNULL(b.MaxPlaces, '20') as MaxPlaces
 FROM BCCharacteristics AS a INNER JOIN Characteristic AS b ON a.CharaID = b.CharaID
WHERE LevID =1 AND a.BCID = @LevelID AND a.CharaID = b.CharaID;

END
```

Comment: Tnx that was the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

It should have worked but you just didn't give an alias to the resulting column, try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLvLValue] 
       @LevID  nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT a.BCID
     , a.CharacteristicID
     , b.CharacteristicName
     , a.LevID, ISNULL(b.MaxPlaces, '20') as MaxPlaces --here was the issue
FROM BCCharacteristics AS a INNER JOIN Characteristic AS b ON a.CharaID = b.CharaID
WHERE LevID =1 AND a.BCID = @LevelID AND a.CharaID = b.CharaID;

END
```